# I can't find the ` apply ` button in subsurf modifier

Tags: mesh, texturing, modifiers, objects, transforms

After I made desired shape with subdivision modifier, how do I turn it into a mesh, there is no `apply` button in modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to click the little down arrow in the modifier options. The apply option is hidden underneath:

[image: Sub]

Comment: It works, THANK YOU !!!